# JAX-WS client get response headers

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I'am trying to implement some logic. I get a HTTP `401` or `403` error after making a call to a WCF service using JAX-WS client (wsimport).

> com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException:  The server sent HTTP
>   status code 401: Unauthorized

How can I get the response headers after making a call? Do I need to implement `SOAPHandler.class`?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP headers can be accessed in a client side in an incoming response. Here is `Handler` code that demonstrates how to do this (See [Access HTTP headers in a Handler](https://metro.java.net/nonav/1.2/guide/Access_HTTP_headers_in_a_Handler.html) for [GlassFish Metro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish_Metro)):

```
public class ClientHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        if (!(Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)) {
            Map<String, List<String>> map = (Map<String, List<String>>) 
                context.get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS);
            List<String> contentType = getHTTPHeader(map, "Content-Type");
            if(contentType != null){
                StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
                for(String type : contentType){
                    strBuf.append(type);
                }
                System.out.println("Content-Type:"+strBuf.toString());
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private @Nullable
    List<String> getHTTPHeader(Map<String, List<String>> headers, String header){
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
            String name = entry.getKey();
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(header))
                return entry.getValue();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution :

```
(Integer) ((BindingProvider) servClient).getResponseContext().get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE);
```